# Drupal 6 - node attached image path

Tags: php, image, path, drupal-6

Drupal 6

I am using `<?php print $node->content['image_attach']['#value'] ?>` in the `node.tpl.php` template file to retrieve the image and getting the image linking to its node.

How can I get the image path only?

EDIT: There is no related CCK field. It is image attach module. Please see https://i.stack.imgur.com/1jYji.jpg

Comment: Hi Dee and welcome to SO. Of which CCK Field type is `image_attach`? Is this a `file upload` field or an `image field`? You normally, inside a template, should be able to load an image field path via the field's machine name (`field_with_image` in this imaginary case): `$field_with_image[0]['filepath']`.

Comment: I cant find the related CCK field in content types, i am attaching a screenshot for the field from the create content page. http://imgur.com/YzyUGZU

Comment: This comes from image Attach module and has no CCK field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly from your comments, you attach an image to a node via the Image Attach submodule of Drupal 6's [Image](https://www.drupal.org/project/image) module.

The way this submodule works is when you attach an image to your node, it creates a new node for that image first and attaches that new node to your original node. In a way similar as how "modern" entity references work in Drupal 7 and 8.

You can confirm that attaching an image creates a new node by going to your `admin/content/node` overview and see a new node of type `image` appear in the listing.

The simplest way of retrieving the information of that node is by fetching it from the information on the current `node` object:

```
$paths = $node->image_attach[0]->images
```

This will retrieve a set of file paths to the various versions of the image. For example:

```
$original_path = $node->image_attach[0]->images['_original']
```

Will link to your original, unaltered image, whereas:

```
$thumbnail_path = $node->image_attach[0]->images['thumbnail']
```

Will link to its thumbnail version (if present).

As you might know, the Image Attach submodule allows for you to add multiple images to your node. In my example I have blindly taken the first image present by using `[0]`. If you have multiple images you should, of course, loop over the various entries present on your `image_attach` array.

If you wish to retrieve even more information about each image node that got attached to your original node, you could also load the *actual node itself* and work with that:

```
$nid = $node->image_attach[0]->nid;
$image_node = node_load($nid);
```

Here you fully load the referenced node and have all of its info available.

The latter case, however, would cause unnecessary overhead for there is no extra information present when fully loading the node. The full reference is already provided by the Image Attach submodule inside of your original `node` object. Just know Image Attach actually creates extra image nodes underwater which you can treat as such.

Comment: Thank you very much for the effort you put in your comment. That was really helpful and appreciated. I also came up with this to retrieve the image path as well.
$image = $node->content["image_attach"]["#value"];
preg_match('/(?<=src=")[^"]*/', $image, $img_url);
print($img_url[0]);

Comment: You are welcome. One point of critic on your own found solution: you are now using `regex` to parse out the path. While `regex` itself seems like magic, it is magic of the darker side. Often is said: *"A programmer who uses `regex` to solve their problem, now has two problems."*. In your case, you will, for instance, not be able to capture different versions of the image. Or if the underlying API changes, your `regex` might not match correctly anymore. If there is a clear solution (via the API in this case), always prefer that over using `regex` (they should be a last, desperate resort).